# Icon to rotate on that detail/summary which is open and clicked

Tags: javascript

When I click the second detail/summary field the icon rotates only on the first detail/summary field and not on the second.

I want the icon to rotate on that detail/summary which is open and clicked.

```js
function changeStyle() {
    let element = document.querySelector(".rotate");
    element.classList.toggle('down');
}
```

```css
.rotate.down {
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}

.detail-container {
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 55%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

summary {
  padding: 22px;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  margin-bottom: .4em;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

   

 .plus {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

details[open] {
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

details[open] summary {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="detail-container">
<details onclick="changeStyle()">           
  <summary>
  <div class="plus">DEFAULT TEXT <i class="fas fa-plus rotate"></i>
   </div>
   </summary>        
    <p>
    Lorem
  </p>

   </details>  
  <details onclick="changeStyle()">
  <summary>
 <div class="plus">DEFAULT TEXT<i class="fas fa-plus rotate"></i>
  </div>
   </summary>

  <p>
  Lorem
  </p>        
</details>
</div>
```

This "+" should rotate for 45 degrees because it is clicked but only the top one rotates
[image: This "+" should rotate for 45 degrees]

Comment: I don't see any issue after running code snippet. what is the issue you're facing with?

Comment: Looks to work fine

Comment: I see your problem, it may not be apparent here. changeStyle queryselects for rotate, but isn't specific to which one, first is assumed to be used each time! The fix here is to give proper reference to what you're clicking

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add all the details (css code) to create a [mre]!. Thank you/

Comment: @BGPHiJACK What would be the way to give proper reference on what I am clicking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector(".rotate")` gets all the `rotate` elements in the document.

You need to get the element which is clicked, then find it's child that you need to rotate:

```js
function changeStyle() {
    let element = event.target.querySelector(".rotate");
    element.classList.toggle('down');
}
```

---

```js
function changeStyle() {
    let element = event.target.querySelector(".rotate");
    element.classList.toggle('down');
}
```

```css
.rotate.down {
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}

summary {
  padding: 22px;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  margin-bottom: .4em;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
summary {
  list-style: none;
} 

 .plus {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

details[open] {
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

details[open] summary {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<details onclick="changeStyle()">           
  <summary>
    <div class="plus">DEFAULT TEXT <i class="fas fa-plus rotate"></i></div>
  </summary>        
  <p>
    Lorem
  </p>
</details>  

<details onclick="changeStyle()">
  <summary>
    <div class="plus">DEFAULT TEXT<i class="fas fa-plus rotate"></i></div>
  </summary>
  <p>
    Lorem
  </p>        
</details>
```